# Partial Layout in Angular JS with new latest routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

```js
/// <reference path="Scripts/angular.js" />
var myApp = angular.module("myModule", ["ngRoute"])
                    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
                        $routeProvider
                            .when("/home", {
                                templateUrl: "homeHTML.html",
                                controller: "homeController"
                            })
                            .when("/courses", {
                                templateUrl: "coursesHTML.html",
                                controller: "coursesController"
                            })
                            .when("/student", {
                                templateUrl: "studentHTML.html",
                                controller: "studentController"
                            })
                    })
                    .controller("homeController", function ($scope) {
                        $scope.message = "Home";
                    })
                    .controller("coursesController", function ($scope) {
                        $scope.message = "Courses";
                    })
                    .controller("studentController", function ($scope) {
                        $scope.message = "Student";
                    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="myModule">
<head>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Script.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="width:600px; height:100px; background-color:#b4b4b4; text-align:center">
                This is the header area
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:200px; height:400px; background-color:#ff0000">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#/home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/courses">Courses</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/student">Student</a></li>
                </ul>
                
            </td>
            <td style="width:400px; height:400px; background-color:#ff6a00">
                <ng-view></ng-view>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="width:500px; height:100px; background-color:#b4b4b4; text-align:center">
                This is a Footer Area
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

homeHTML, studentHTML, coursesHTML all are same as below.

```
<h1>{{message}}</h1>
<div>
    <p>Hi this is home partial view</p>
</div>
```

I found this error in the snippet part

```
Error:{
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 51,
  "colno": 13
}
```

What happened here is I get the view as shown in snippet with no errors in the browser and also when i click links home, courses, student nothing appears.
Please point out what went wrong here.

Comment: you should not put the script tag in head but rather should put script tags before body ends and make sure anular.min.js is loading

Comment: no that does not create any issues. you can keep script any where in html but it is prefered to keep in head section or begininng of boday tag in angular JS application.

Answer (score 0):

Guyss I found out the answer

```
/// <reference path="Scripts/angular.min.js" />
var myApp = angular.module("myModule", ["ngRoute"])
                    .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
                        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
                        $routeProvider
                            .when("/home", {
                                templateUrl: "homeHTML.html",
                                controller: "homeController"
                            })
                            .when("/courses", {
                                templateUrl: "coursesHTML.html",
                                controller: "coursesController"
                            })
                            .when("/student", {
                                templateUrl: "studentHTML.html",
                                controller: "studentController"
                            })
                    })
                    .controller("homeController", function ($scope) {
                        $scope.message = "Home";
                    })
                    .controller("coursesController", function ($scope) {
                        $scope.message = "Courses";
                    })
                    .controller("studentController", function ($scope) {
                        $scope.message = "Student";
                    });
```

I have added $locationProvider. I will update the reason soon.

Comment: there is some sort of bug in latest version of routes

Answer (score 0):

First define angular module in your html or body tag and make sure your angular version is same as angular-router version.Also don't forget to define respective controllers in homeHTML.html, coursesHTML.html and studentHTML.html

homeHTML.html

```
<div ng-controller="homeController">

    <h1>{{ message }}</h1>

</div>
```

Its working for me.

check out this link : https://plnkr.co/edit/cZzk8EKBXqRuoy6oYhuF?p=preview

Comment: Hey thanx syed. I posted the answer where issue was created.